# Drawing Outlines

Tags: rendering, outliner

Below is the sort of effect I am trying to apply : [image]
Youtube instructions led me to using "solidify" modifier as a way, and the instruction was that :

1. Add material that is totally black without any gloss, as this will become the outline itself
2. Tick "Backface Culling"
3. With 2 materials applied on the "material properties" option, apply solidify modifier
4. On solidify modifier,

- Tick "flip normals"
- Tick "material offset" to 1

But now that I have followed all these, I'm only getting that black material I added on the first step. Here is a screenshot : [image]

**Material Properties Tab**

[image]

**Modifier Properties Tab**

[image]

What am I missing and how can I make mine to look like the reference image at the very top? :'(

Thanks for reading this far and thanks always for your help guys :)

Comment: I think all you need to do is swap your materials in their material slots (ie Material1 goes in slot 2 - Material2 goes in slot 1). You can do it by selecting the material in the box where the 2 of them are listed (material slot box), and then change the material by clicking on the "globe" underneath, on the same line where it says "data". Click and select the "other" material. Do this for both slots.

Comment: Another thing to try is to change the offset of the solidify modifier (not material offset - the one under thickness) from -1 to 1 (inward to outward). Also make the thickness positive as well.

Comment: Do you mean swapping the order of the materials? I did so and its still not working :( 
Also when I click the globe it only has list of the materials I used and doesnt have the other option

Comment: ++ changing offsets still show it black as above

Comment: ++ Additional info : duplicating the object I want an outliner to only adds the outliner on viewport, and still appears black like above on render

Comment: Here's a link to a file where I got it working. Have a look at the setup and see if you can see what's going on - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7vLzJpPV/. It also works with a negative thickness on the solidify modifier.